# How to extract one type of value from an array to create a separate array one by one?

Tags: swift

I am trying to extract just the id's from the Properties Array to form a separate array. So far I have come up with this:

```
struct Interactions: View {

@State var A: [Properties] = [
    .init(id: 5, name: "Five"),
    .init(id: 8, name: "Eight"),
    .init(id: 2, name: "Two")
]
var body: some View {

    List(loadIdArray(), id: \.self) { i in
        Text("\(i)")
    }


}

func loadIdArray() -> [Int] {

    let ids: [Int] = [1, 2]
    for i in 0 ..< self.A.count {
        let ids = [self.A[i].id, self.A[i + 1].id]
        return ids
    }
    return ids
}
}
```

The problem is that I would have to manually type each [self.A[I + ...].id] which defeats the purpose of the function.

The answer I want is for loadIdArray() = [5, 8, 2] and for it to do this automatically depending on how many items are in the 'A' array.

Comment: You should start by separating your view and your model; This is very important in SwiftUI as it is declarative.  Once you have a model to hold your array, you can use a computed variable to provide an Array with the ids

Comment: @Paulw11 would you by any chance be able to write that out as code? I think it's a problem with my iteration as it only presents one self.A.id and has to be manually typed out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about using this:

```
func loadIdArray() -> [Int] {
    return self.A.map { $0.id }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been stuck on this for way too long